# Automatically reference a set of equations in align

Tags: equations, align, labels

Is there a way to automatically refer to a set of equations in an `align` environment?

E.G. I would like this to read "From Eqs.(1-3), we can clearly see..."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{align}\label{eqn:myeqs}
    x =& y\\
    y = \sqrt{x-q}\\
    z =& y-20l
  \end{align}

  \begin{equation}\label{eqn:somethingelse}
    E = \hbar \omega
  \end{equation}

  From Eqs. \ref{eqn:myeqs}, we can clearly see...
\end{document}
```

I've seen [a way to do this manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35921/multiple-subequation-labels-in-one-ref), but I'm curious to see if there's a simple, automated way to handle this.

Comment: You could add a label to both the first and the last line in the `align` and use `cleveref`s `\crefrange` as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18986/is-there-a-standard-way-to-refer-to-a-range-of-equations/18988#18988  Edit: Sorry, the formatting is a little different.

Comment: This plus a quick `\crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}` got me exactly to what I need! Would you be able to submit this as answer so I can give you credit? I realize its similar to the previous one, but I tried numerous search terms and couldn't arrive at it so it may be helpful to others to have this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a label to both the first and last equation in an `align`, and use `cleveref`s `\crefrange{first label}{second label}` to create the reference. The format of the references printed by `cleveref` can be modified as described in chapter 8 of the manual.

Some additional points:

- In an `align` the `&` should be placed before the `=`, not after, as you had in your code. Having it after leads to wrong spacing.
- If you use `hyperref`, `cleveref` should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    x &= y    \label{eq:a}\\
    y &= \sqrt{x-q}\\
    z &= y-20l  \label{eq:b}
\end{align}
From \crefrange{eq:a}{eq:b}, we can clearly see\ldots

\Crefrange{eq:a}{eq:b} shows \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: @orbjørn-t
This worked for me. Thanks.