# multiple subequations same line with reference compact

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, align, labels, subequations

I posted a question earlier,

[multiple subequations same line with reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249791/multiple-subequations-same-line-with-reference)

But I'd like to be able to combine the numbering at the end of the line for the following two cases:

```
Re = UL/nu , Ha = BL sqrt(sigma/(rho nu)),   Re_m = mu sigma UL      (4a,4b,4c)
```

And

```
Re = UL/nu , Ha = BL sqrt(sigma/(rho nu)),   Re_m = mu sigma UL      (4-6)
```

This code has all numbers, but they're in-between

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}XXX@{}}
        \begin{equation}
            Re = \frac{U L}{\nu}, \label{eq:UBCs_D100}
        \end{equation} &
        \begin{equation}
            Ha = B L \sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\rho \nu}}, \label{eq:UBCs_D200}
        \end{equation}
        \begin{equation}
            Re_m = \mu_{m} \sigma U L \label{eq:UBCs_N00}
        \end{equation}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, very unusual request ... however if you persist, try

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
        \begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}XXXc@{}}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:UBCs_D100}
    Re = \frac{U L}{\nu},                       \notag
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}  &
\begin{equation}\label{eq:UBCs_D200}
    Ha = B L \sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\rho \nu}},    \notag
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}  &
\begin{equation} \label{eq:UBCs_N00}            \notag
    Re_m = \mu_{m} \sigma U L
\end{equation}
                & (\ref{eq:UBCs_D100},\ref{eq:UBCs_D200},\ref{eq:UBCs_N00})
    \end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:UBCs_N100}           
    a = b
\end{equation}
```

From above code you should catch idea, how to manage your problem. I didn't bother with formatting as you not provide MWE (which can be compiled).

[image]

**Edit:**
An another solution with better formatting of equations. Here instead `tabularx` is used `minipage`s aligned at their bottom:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

        \begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.28\hsize}
\begin{equation}[b]\label{eq:UBCs_D100}
    Re = \frac{U L}{\nu},                       \notag
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.28\hsize}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:UBCs_D200}
    Ha = B L \sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{\rho \nu}},    \notag
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.28\hsize}
\vskip-5pt
\begin{equation} \label{eq:UBCs_N00}            \notag
    Re_m = \mu_{m} \sigma U L
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hfill(\ref{eq:UBCs_D100},\ref{eq:UBCs_D200},\ref{eq:UBCs_N00})
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:UBCs_N100}
    a = b
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Interestingly, both solution only works with `equation` environment. At use of `gather` or other `amsmath` environments the sub-equations labels are lost.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a MWE.. but the solution you provided has the same numbering for all the equations (1a,1a,1a) and does not alternate (1a,1b,1c)..

Comment: @Charlie, already the first edit of my answer gives correct labeling, with second one I just improve formatting of equations (with uise of minipages), now they are in line.

Comment: @Charlie, I'm just curious, do my answer (with improved formatting) fulfill your expectation? If not, please clarify your question or describe, what is missing in it.

Comment: Yep! looks great! Sorry for the late response!