# Multiple equations in one line with proper referencing

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, subequations, ref

I am looking for a way to have several equations in the same line, and being able to reference them. I know this can be done for multiple rows with `eqnarray`, but I want it in one line.

I have the following workaround, which is not good:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqs}
\mbox{\textbf{(i)}}   \ \ x>y  \ \ \ \ \ \  
\mbox{\textbf{(ii)}}  \ \ y>z  \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\mbox{\textbf{(iii)}} \ \ z>a  \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{equation}

equation reference (\ref{eqs}\textbf{(i)}), (\ref{eqs}\textbf{(ii)}), (\ref{eqs}\textbf{(iii)}).
```

This looks as:

[image]

Is there a proper way of achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple subequations same line with reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249791/multiple-subequations-same-line-with-reference)

Comment: But the labelling in the duplicate is different to the request here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `enumitem` hiding the list in an `mbox`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{eqlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[eqlist]{itemjoin=\quad,mode=unboxed,label=(\roman*),ref=\theequation(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{17}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:three}
  \mbox{%
  \begin{eqlist}
  \item\label{eqi:th-one} \( x>y\),
  \item\label{eqi:th-two} \( y>z\),
  \item\label{eqi:th-three} \( \displaystyle z>\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^{2}}dx \).
  \end{eqlist}}
\end{equation}
Referencing (\ref{eqi:th-two}).

\end{document}
```

However, this will not work with `amsmath` (because of the multiple label commands) and does not allow multiple lines.  A varation solving both problems is the following, based on `minipage`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}

\newlist{eqlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\makeatletter
\setlist[eqlist]{itemjoin=\quad,mode=unboxed,label=(\roman*),
  ref=\theequation(\roman*),before={\let\label\ltx@label}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{17}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:three}
  \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}\centering
  \begin{eqlist}
  \item\label{eqi:th-one} \( x>y\),
  \item\label{eqi:th-two} \( y>z\),
  \item\label{eqi:th-three} \( \displaystyle z>\int_{0}^{1}
    e^{x^{2}}dx \),\endgraf
    \item\label{eqi:th-four} \( \displaystyle a = \int_{U} \frac{\cos
      x}{\sin y}\,dx\,dy\).
  \end{eqlist}
\end{minipage}
\end{equation}
Referencing \eqref{eqi:th-two} and \eqref{eqi:th-four}.

\end{document}
```